# In angular what is difference between a node package and an angular 6 library?

Tags: angular, angular6, node-modules, angular-library

I am new to angular and I understand the fact that in angular, node dependencies are stored in node_modules folder. Since I am working on angular 6, I have come across concept of angular libraries. When I have to import an angular library in an application along with some common angular dependencies in package.json then after npm install the angular library also gets stored in node_modules folder along with other dependencies. This lead me to think that regular node dependencies and angular libraries both can be imported in similar way as dependencies from package.json which makes me wonder **what benefit I can achieve by an angular library which can not be achieved by a node package?**

Before even angular 6 library concept, I used to create an angular application and used to publish it (either on private repositories like jfrog or to public npm repository) as node package/module and everyone could use it by adding it as dependency.

**I have gone through angular 6 library feature and have questions like what I can do extra which I could not do before?**

Links i have gone through:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5
   https://medium.com/@suwigyarathore/write-your-own-library-in-angular-6-741d44d4a356
   https://medium.com/@SirMaxxx/angular-6-creating-a-shareable-control-library-6a27f0ebe5c2
   https://angular.io/guide/libraries

Comment: You're last link answers all your questions. Libraries are more extensible then node modules. Why does where it's stored or how it's imported matter at all?

Comment: A published angular library at the base level is a npm package. The whole point of an angular library though is to extend angular functionality. It's a standalone angular project that cannot run on it's own. Primarily you would create an angular library to create some sort of component, directive, service, or similar that will be used in another angular project. It really depends on what you are trying to create. If you are just trying to create a package that does something like currency formatting or something not angular specific, then that probably does not need to be an angular library.

Comment: If however you are trying to create an `NgModule` with pipes and components that do something for currency formatting for example, that that would probably be a great use case for an angular library. Any other angular project can import/use this library. Also  what you are getting from @angular/cli or similar in terms of developing and publishing libraries includes tools/mechanisms to avoid bundling invalid dependencies (such as bundling angular as a dependency instead of a peer dependency). So you really need to narrow down your question and explain what you are trying to achieve specifically

Comment: I'm working in an enterprise application,where container application is made of small independent but complex business application such as A,B and C.And this container application have a dependency of these small business application.These small application solves complex business requirements and can have several components,directives,pipes in it.

what would be great way to use these small applications as package in container application:

EITHER publish small applications as npm package OR as angular library in private repository.

And use as a dependency in a container application.